# Questions about writing a program in Java using Digital signature

Tags: java

> Write two programs - one for Alice, another for Bob. Data exchange between them is achieved through a text file used as a communication channel.

I keep getting an error in Netbeans:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Signature.encode

Can anyone help steer me in the right direction? I can post the error message if needed; it shows Alice's keys and extended messsage but nothing about Bob.
I can also post the lab directions if needed as well.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Signature {
    static class Keys {
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger("9617");
        BigInteger d = new BigInteger("3869");
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger("17");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Keys keys = new Keys();
        String message = "What's up Bob";
        int blockSize = 4;


        Signature obj = new Signature();


        System.out.println("Alice's keys:");
        System.out.println("e: " + keys.e);
        System.out.println("d: " + keys.d);
        System.out.println("n: " + keys.n);
        while (message.length() % (blockSize / 2) != 0) {
            message += "-";
        }
        /
        System.out.println(
            "Alice's extended message:\n" +
            message);
        String encodedMsg = obj.encode(message);
        String signature = obj.dosignature(
            encodedMsg, keys.d, keys.n, blockSize);

        System.out.println(
            "Alice's digital signature\n" +
            signature);
        String signedMsg = message + "_" + signature;

        System.out.println(
            "Alice's signed message:\n" +
            signedMsg);
        String extractedMsgText =
            signedMsg.substring(
                0, signedMsg.indexOf('_'));

        System.out.println(
            "Bob's extracted message text:\n" +
            extractedMsgText);
        String extractedSignature =
            signedMsg.substring(
                signedMsg.indexOf('_') + 1);
        System.out.println(
            "Bob's extracted digital signature:\n" +
            extractedSignature);
        String decipheredSignature;
        decipheredSignature = obj.doRSA(extractedSignature, keys.e, keys.n, blockSize);

        String decodedSignature = obj.decode(
            decipheredSignature);
        System.out.println(
            "Bob's decoded digital signature:\n" +
            decodedSignature);
        if (extractedMsgText.equals(decodedSignature)) {
            System.out.println(
                "Bob's conclusion: Valid signature");
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                "Bob's conclusion: Invalid signature");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to run Java code that doesn't even compile. Don't do that. Read the errors you get from the compiler, fix them all, and then , and only then, execute the code. Also, indent your code. Your IDE can do that for you with a single keyboard shortcut. Not indented code is unreadable.

Comment: So you handed in an assignment that does not compile, yet you are astonished that your professor didn't give you a reason for rejecting the solution as 'wrong'?

Comment: I was just wondering they are any stand out errors.Iam trying to fix but i a stuck on i should do next.Thaks JB i will do as you said.

Comment: Re, "I can post the error message if needed."  The error message is _always_ needed.  If your question is about an error message that you do not understand, then you will get a better quality of answer if you show the message the the people from whom you are asking help.

Answer (score 0):

Class `Signature` does not have an `encode` method.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15708776)

Comment: Well, the question was: "Can anyone help steer me in the right direction?" -- and this is one direction. For me the root of the problem.